# Finder - No Services Apply

Tags: macos, services

I have services set up, particularly the one for opening Terminal from a folder.  However, it doesn't appear in the context menu and in Finder > Services, there is nothing except "No services apply"

I'm using El Capitan 10.11.6

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Have you checked "System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Services" this ist the part that you can enable shortcuts from the context menu.

Comment: I my option, this type of service would not appear on the menu bar. So "No services apply" is probably correct. Try right clicking on the folder in a Finder window and looking there for the service.

Comment: According to tutorials I've followed, it should be a context menu option in every folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to click on a file or folder to select it and then the Services menu will work. You can get to the Services from either the Finder menu bar or by Control-clicking (right-clicking) on an item.

Comment: Ahh, this does work for folders, but not in column view.  However, it will only work from the menu bar along the top.  The directions I was following say that I can have access by right clicking inside a folder and opening up terminal from the context menu.